# Facebook application domain settings

Tags: facebook, dns, facebook-like

we were working on our sandbox trying to get the facebook like button set up for our site. Like an idiot, I set our sandbox URL as the domain. Here's the question: is there any going back once I've done this? I tried to reset the domain but it doesn't seem to have taken.

And, here's a related question: if i just go and make a like button (iFrame version) it spits out an app_id as part of the code. If that app_id isn't hooked up to an actual application w/domain, will it work after we move it to our QA server and then on to production? Or will it, once we've tested on our sandbox, establish the sandbox as it's domain and then we're back where we started?

We can't change code once it moves on to QA, it's just bad form...so what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:

```
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
```

once you set up og:url property which is the canonical url of your domain at the same time your canvas url, you will be done

Here example:

```
Url to like = "http://myapp.com"
<meta property="og:url" content="http://myapp.com/" />    
Canvas URL: "http://myapp.com"
```

Comment: Yes, but what if we're not even at the point where we're setting up an application in Facebook? Do I even need a canvas URL? Is it required for doing something as simple as a like button?

Comment: But I do WANT the article link to get posted on their page. This WAS happening, but when we moved onto QA it stopped working. I THOUGHT the problem was the fact that I had put the site URL and domain as our sandbox, not the live site. In any case, when the file was moved to our qa server (which is not open externally) it caused a problem that wasn't there before. My husband suggested that the reason is that facebook won't post likes from a site "it can't see," and this might be true, but then how do our QA people test it for functionality? Are they just supposed to take it on faith? Am I?